# Cual es la diferencia entre estos operadores para estructuras?

Tags: c

- Tengo una duda, cual es la diferencia entre, por ejemplo...

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>

  struct persona{
  char nombre[20];
  };

  int main (){
  persona *k;

  k = (persona *) calloc (2, sizeof(persona));
  k[0].nombre; // la duda esta aca, cual es la diferencia entre estos dos
  *(k+0)->nombre;   

  return 0;
   }
  ```
- Por otro lado tengo una duda. Un arreglo es un conjunto de variables que se declaran contiguamente en la memoria, sin embargo, aun no se me ha respondido la duda de si es que pasa lo mismo con las estructuras...

Comment: El código que proporcionas no compila.

Comment: La idea no es que compile. Tengo una duda no un error, si compilara no podría presentar ambos casos con los que me estoy debatiendo...

Comment: Esto: `*(k+0)->nombre` está mal, el operador `*` no va ahí. El código debería ser: `(k+0)->nombre`. Con respecto a sus diferencias, no la hay, ambos hacen  lo mismo: *acceder a los miembros de la estructura*, lo que cambia es su sintaxis y como recomendación, por cada duda, **haz una pregunta diferente.**

Comment: @MrDave1999 Exacto, lo descubrí ayer, me di cuenta de que *(k + 0) no tiene sentido, por cierto, estas en todos lados MrDave1999, aprecio eso, gracias por la ayuda .

Comment: @Santiago Me da gusto que lo hayas resuelto. No olvides de [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/105299) que resolvió tu problema (lo menciono por las preguntas que has hecho).

Answer (score -1):

Eso se llama aritmetica de punteros son  variables que guardan direcciones de memoria la cuales basicamente son integer, los punteros solo apuntan al primer slot de memoria A[0] es igual a decia *(a + 0) para acceder al valor y al estructuras en memoria trabaja asi ejemplo

```
struct tal {
  int a, //4 bytes
  int b  //4 bytes
  char c //1 byte
}
```

Entonces el tamaño de la estructura seria de 9 bytes en teoria pero eso casi nunca es asi porque aveces hay slot de memorias continuos que no pueda alocar ese dato ejemplo : despues de char c tienes otro int el cual es 4 bytes mas pero el slot de memoria que sigue solo puede alocar 2 entonces el salta ese slot y aloca en el otro entonces ya cambia el tamaño int a + int b + char c y int d + los 2 bytes que salto porque no podia alocar en memoria ese dato. tu estas haciendo un array de estructuras de 2 personas entonces para ingresar al valor como tal de todo los elementos A[0]->nombre A[0]->loquesea

Comment: Esta respuesta contiene demasiados errores prácticos y conceptuales.